# Merging of accounts

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I had to create a new account due circumstances beyond my control. I already have an account with the same user name (kuku) and I was wondering if someone could merge my accounts. I tried to ask over at meta, but didn't have enough rep.   Thanks.

Comment: You may want to mention what the original account was...

Comment: the account had the same user name i.e. kuku.  If it helps, this is one of the question I asked with the original account: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70415/showing-that-mathbbr-is-connected]

Answer (score 5):

Please try [the suggestions found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist):

> 1. Set the email address of your registered account to the address used in your other account. Since email is not visible to anyone, this will confirm that you own both accounts. Note that the system may prevent this.
> 2. If you provided your "real name" in the original profile, adding it to your new one can also help to remove doubt about the ownership of both accounts. Obviously, this is pointless if your "real name" is also your display name. You might also consider filling in your birthdate, if you provided *that* on your original account...
> 3. If possible, [add the OpenID (or other credentials) you used on your original account to your new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers).
> 4. **Wait**. There are [automated processes that merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89694/why-have-my-two-accounts-been-merged-without-asking-me/89790#89790). Wait a bit to see if things are resolved automatically.
> 5. [Flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review) one of your posts for moderator attention and ask for a merge:
>
>    > [image: mod flag]
>
>    If the details match, we will go ahead and merge with no further ado. If we feel we need more confirmation for some reason, we will either comment or email to tell you.
> 6. Wait some more.
> 7. If all else fails, email the administrators using the "contact us" link found at the bottom of every page, noting the URL of both accounts in your request.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @kuku: like Shog9 said, please edit your new account to show your real name and/or e-mail a moderator (me, for example) with the e-mail address you used for your old account. I'm pretty convinced you are who you say you are, but want to make double sure.

Comment: @WillieWong: Unfortunately, I've misplaced the password for the email address used in creating the original account. Also, I never had my real name on real(full name) on the original account. Is there anything else I can do besides waiting? Thanks.

Comment: @Kuku: What we want is a piece of non-publicly displayed information. For example, if you can tell us which e-mail address (you don't have to send the e-mail from there) you used to create your previous account, that'd be fine. Or you can edit your new account to use the same "real name" as that you used to create your old account. It doesn't have to be a real name. All we are asking for is some piece of non-public information which can be used to show that you are who you claim you are.